# Matrices and coordinate system

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

How can I draw the function x+y=n with n not greater than 10 and the coordinate system using only matrices without any functions or libraries? I am a beginner and I hope you could help me.The only problem is that my code prints spaces above the line x+y=n and it should not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    int n, i, j;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    char m[12][63] = { " " };
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            m[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 && j == 1)
                m[i][j] = '0';
            if (i == 11 && j == 61)
                m[i][j] = '2';
            if (j == 0 && i != 0 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '0' + 10 - i;
            if (j == 2 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '+';
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '0' + ((j - 2) / 3) % 10;
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 1 && j > 29 && j < 59)
                m[i][j] = '1';
            if (i == 10 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '+';
        }
    }
     for(i=1;i<n+1;i++){
         if((10-n+i)!=10 && (2+3*i)!=1)
        m[10-n+i][2+3*i]='*';
        }
    m[0][0]='1';
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//n=5
 10+
 9 +
 8 +
 7 +
 6 +
 5 +
 4 +  *
 3 +     *
 2 +        *
 1 +           *
 0 +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all its quite difficult for me to understand your logic behind the `if` statements in the `for` loop.

With that said,  to get the desired 10+ on the y-axis i set `m[0][0] = '1';` which seems to work.

As for drawing the line, it seems that:

```
if (j == 3 * (n + i - 10) && i > 2 && j > 2)  m[i][j] = '*';
```

was causing the issues. I replaced it with:

```
m[10 - n][2] = '*';

    for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        m[10 - n + i][2 + 3 * i] = '*';
    }
```

and it works fine and in a more understandable way hopefully!

So in the end the code should look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char m[12][63] = { " " };

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            m[i][j] = ' ';
            
            if (i == 0 && j == 1) m[i][j] = '0';
            if (i == 11 && j == 61) m[i][j] = '2';
            if (j == 0 && i != 0 && i != 11) m[i][j] = '0' + 10 - i;
            if (j == 2 && i != 11) m[i][j] = '+';
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 2) m[i][j] = '0' + ((j - 2) / 3) % 10;
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 1 && j > 29 && j < 59) m[i][j] = '1';
            if (i == 10 && j % 3 == 2) m[i][j] = '+';
          // if (j == 3 * (n + i - 10) && i > 2 && j > 2)  m[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }

    m[10 - n][2] = '*'; // sets + on y-axis to *

    for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        m[10 - n + i][2 + 3 * i] = '*'; // draws * diagonally jumping 3 characters (thus 3*i)
    }

    m[0][0] = '1'; // to have 10 instead of 0 at the top left
    
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        }  printf("\n");
    }
}
```

For `n=7` for example you get the desired:

```
10+
9 +
8 +
7 *
6 +  *
5 +     *
4 +        *
3 +           *
2 +              *
1 +                 *
0 +  +  +  +  +  +  +  *  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

To not delete the `+`  by the `*`  just offset the line to the right:

```
m[10 - n][3] = '*'; 

for (i = 1; i < n+1 ; i++)
{
    m[10 - n + i ][3 + 3 * i] = '*'; // draws * diagonally jumping 3 characters (thus 3*i)
}

m[0][0] = '1'; // to have 10 instead of 0 at the top left
```

So the `n=7` example should now look:

```
10+
9 +
8 +
7 +*
6 +   *
5 +      *
4 +         *
3 +            *
2 +               *
1 +                  *
0 +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +* +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

In order to not print `chars` above or after the line try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    char m[12][63] = { " " };
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            m[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 && j == 1)
                m[i][j] = '0';
            if (i == 11 && j == 61)
                m[i][j] = '2';
            if (j == 0 && i != 0 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '0' + 10 - i;
            if (j == 2 && i != 11)
                m[i][j] = '+';
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '0' + ((j - 2) / 3) % 10;
            if (i == 11 && j % 3 == 1 && j > 29 && j < 59)
                m[i][j] = '1';
            if (i == 10 && j % 3 == 2)
                m[i][j] = '+';


        }
    }

    

    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if ((10 - n + i) != 10 && (2 + 3 * i) != 1)
            m[10 - n + i][2 + 3 * i] = '*';

            
    }

    m[0][0] = '1';

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++)
        {
            if ((i < 10 - n) || (j > 2 + 3 * n))
            {
                m[i][j] = '\0';
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 63; j++) {
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and for `n=5` you get:

```
5 +
4 +  *
3 +     *
2 +        *
1 +           *
0 +  +  +  +  +  +
  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would you solve this without using if statements?

Comment: And the asteriks shouldn't be drawn instead of plus (example: if n=7, asteriks shouldn't be drawn instead of plus when x=7 or y=7

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using if statements and its quite inevitable to avoid them so thats what i would use. My comment was about you implementing them in a hard way to read and thus understand, which doesnt make them wrong though!

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with asteriks and pluses(I added the new code to the question, so you can see the new code there). One more question:I should not have any spaces after asteriks, so how can I erase these spaces?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Try drawing your desired result on something like notepad and paste it here, to figure it out. However keep in mind that we are pushing the console to its limits with this project. Don't except perfect results!

Comment: The only problem is that my code prints spaces above the line x+y=n and it should not print any signs after that line. If it prints any signs after that line, the result is not accepted. I added the result to the question above, and everything is correct except these spaces which are not visible.

Comment: I'm still missing something here. By using the instruction `m[ i ][ j ] = '  ';`  you can't get rid of the spaces in your matrix and i also don't see the issue of having invisible spaces above the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226834/discussion-between-mr-simple-thoughts-and-michael).